# Castle Windsor register closed - open generic

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, decorator, open-generics

```cs
public interface IProcess {}

public interface IProcessHandler<in TProcess> where TProcess : IProcess {
    void Handle(TProcess message);
}

public class AccessMessage<TProcess> : IProcess where TProcess : IProcess {
    public virtual string Username {get;protected set;}
    public virtual TProcess InnerProcess { get; protected set; }
}

public class AccessMessageHandler<TProcess> : IProcessHandler<AccessMessage<TProcess>> where TProcess : IProcess {
    public AccessMessageHandler(IProcessHandler<TProcess> innerHandler){}
    public void Handle(AccessMessage<TProcess> message){
      // access control
      _innerHandler.Handle(message.InnerProcess)
    }
}

public class JustDoIt : IProcess {}

public class JustDoItHandle : IProcessHandler<JustDoIt> {
    public void Handle(JustDoIt message) {
      // handle
    }
}

container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
                               .BasedOn(typeof(IProcessHandler<>))
                               .If(t => t.Name.Contains("AccessMessageHandler") == false)
                               .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                               .LifestyleTransient()
                               .AllowMultipleMatches());

// container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IProcessHandler<AccessMessage<>>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(AccessMessageHandler<>))); // compiler not allowed this this 
// container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IProcessHandler<AccessMessage<IProcess>>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(AccessMessageHandler<>))); // error when resolving (No component for supporting the service)

var handler = Container.Resolve<IProcessHandler<AccessMessageHandler<JustDoIt>>>();
    handler.Handle(new AccessMessage(new JustDoIt(),"username"));
```

how can I register IProcessHandler> ?

Comment: Did you try this: `container.Register(Component.For(typeof (IProcessHandler<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(AccessMessageHandler<>)))`?

Comment: @Steven I don't want to implement AccessMessageHandler<> for all IProcessHandler<>, AccessMessageHandler should handle only AccessMessage<TCommand> process

Comment: yes i tried, "Dependency cycle has been detected when trying to resolve component "

Comment: how can I implement this in Simple Injector? last night I changed my Ioc container to Simpler Injector. I implemented open generic decorators but I can't implement AccessMessageHandler for AccessMessage<TProcess>

Comment: That's just a matter of doing:
`using SimpleInjector.Extensions;`
`container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IProcessHandler<>), typeof(AccessMessageHandler<>));`

Comment: AccessMessageHandler must handle AccessMessage<T>, when I register like this, container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IProcessHandler<>), applicationAssembly);
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IProcessHandler<>), typeof(AccessMessageHandler<>)); an error occured on resolving

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728256/how-can-i-register-an-open-generic-type-with-a-complex-type-constraint-in-simple